# iOS: Multiple language / Mulitple apps, will they be rejected in app store?

Tags: ios, internationalization, app-store

I know there are a bunch of questions out there about multiple language issue on iOS, and I AM AWARE that the good, civilised way of doing this is by making use of Apple's internationalisation tools.

However, I have a customer that is absolutely determined that he prefers to have multiple apps instead of a single one. This is really out of my control.

My question is, will the app(s) be **rejected**????

I've tried to find a place in the documentation that explicitly states that multiple apps will be rejected but I haven't found anything. I've heard horror stories about it but on the other hand, I have seen some multiple language/multiple apps in the app store. I've even written an e-mail to the review guys at Apple without a reply.

Do you have any experience in the matter? Has anyone attempted to do this with a negative outcome?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Oh God. Please don't do this. What possible reason could the customer have? Talk it through with them - this could lead to a worse user experience and therefore sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the app will most likely be rejected if the "multiple-app" approach is taken.

Apple approval process is not exact, but theoretically they will not allow this... and the excuse "other's have done it" will not work with the reviewers :)